# Regex to ignore whitespace

Tags: regex

Consider 2 of the following:

1. trans( 'Hello' )
2. trans('Hello')

My regex: `trans\(([\'"])(((?!\1).)*)\1\)`

The above works well with the 2. case but does not work with case 1.
I tried adding another capturing group (/s) but then 2. does not work while 1. does.
Is there a way to have both detected?

Comment: what about: `trans( 'Hello')` or `trans('Hello' )` ?

Comment: I am not considering those cases for now. these case are very rare and can be manually corrected.

Comment: perhaps your issue is that `/s` does not match whitespace. For that, usually `\s` is required

Comment: @jhnc yes, realized that. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work as it's simply modifying your expression to support any number of whitespaces on either side of the quotes:

```
trans\(\s*([\'"])(((?!\1).)*)\1\s*\)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following pattern seems to work here:

```regex
trans\((\s*)(['"])(.*?)\2\1\)
```

### Demo

Here we capture optional whitespace before the singly quoted term, and then ensure that we also match the same as `\1` after that term.  For those inputs having whitespace, we assert that we see the same whitespace afterwards.  For inputs not having whitespace, then `\1` should be empty.

Comment: Thanks. But i am looking the to extract the string within. With the above regex, I am unable to get the string within the quotes. The one i shared works for that purpose. I just want to enhance it a bit to accommodate whitespaces before and after the quotes

Comment: @Simeon Then just add a second capture group around the quoted term.  This should not be a problem assuming that your regex tool supports capture groups.

Comment: Yes I tried this trans\((\s*)([\'"])(((?!\1).)*)\1\), works fine for case 1. but fails in case 2.

Comment: You keep using your regex, which doesn't work.  It is working in my answer.  Did you bother to check the demo?

Comment: I did try the first time(before the edited answer), which wasn't what I was looking for even though it detected it. Using the edited answer works. I will need to handle double quotes as well. That's why I was using mine as the base

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want symmetrical quotes and whitespace, and to capture the string in between.

`trans\((\s*)(['"])(((?!\2).)*)\2\1\)`

The string is in $3.